# scikit-learn hyper-parameter tuning: Can you print results as it's executing?

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameters

When using scikit-learn for hyper-parameter tuning, is there a way of printing the results as the code executes?
For instance, something like:

value of parameters tried, score of evaluation metric obtanied, ...

for every iteration the optimization searches for.

Comment: You can get details by passing parameter `verbose` to both [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) and [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) for instance...

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, but you may need to set `n_jobs=1` to get all the verbose printings.